# using an onClick event to trigger a CSS3 transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am experimenting with css3 transitions and want to introduce an onClick event to trigger the transition instead of the pseudo hover class. The problem I have is that the transition is split onto two elements.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="box"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt=""/>
<div class="mask">
<!-- Further content goes here -->
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 2px #E6171A;              
}

.mask {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #021288;
     -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.box:hover .mask {
     -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: .4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    -ms-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.box img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1.3s;
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.box:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
    -o-transform: translateX(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
    transform: translateX(300px);
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .8s;
    -o-transition-delay: .8s;
    -ms-transition-delay: .8s;
    transition-delay: .8s;
/* the delay goes in the hover(action state) to overide the delay in the original state     */
}
```

So the question is how do I apply the onClick event to a transition that is spread over two elements? Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `:hover` with a class, something like `clicked`

```
.box.clicked
```

Then on click, use `addClass` to add that the `clicked` class to `.box`. That change should trigger the animation originally done by `:hover`.

[Here's an example using `toggleClass` to add/remove the class on click and change the `height` of the div.](http://jsfiddle.net/fgvr2/)